# How to replace a single byte in a binary file using awk

Tags: unix, awk, sh

I am trying to reverse engineer a Linux box to flash my own firmware, but to do that I need to patch a binary file. The patch is actually quite simple, I just need to alter one byte at a known offset. However, the Linux box doesn't have any programs like dd, sed, awk, etc. Not even telnet (I am communicating with it over serial). However, it does have sh. Is there a way to replace a byte at a known offset just using shell commands?

Thank you.

Comment: If it has `sh` why have you tagged as `bash`? Which please?

Comment: Does it have any scripting language (Perl, Python, Ruby)? Does it have a C compiler, or do you know how to crosscompile for it?

Comment: A posix system should have `sed` installed. If that isn't the case here, then you cannot even be sure that there are basic things like `echo` available (if we are talking about plain `sh` and not `bash`, which has a builtin `echo`). To answer this question, you have to give us more information on what exactly is available.

Comment: Sorry, it's `sh`, not `bash`. It does not have any scripting languages, and even if I could cross compile for it, I would not be able to transfer the file over. However, I do have `echo`.

Comment: Is *any* editor available, say, `ed`?

Comment: Nope, I have to use `cat << EOF > file`

Answer (score 1):

If you have `head -c` (the `-c` option is not specified by posix), `printf` and `tail` available, then this should work:

```
file=pathToYourFile
address=1234 # `address=1` changes the first byte
newByteOctal=567
{
  head -c "$((address-1))" "$file"
  printf "\\0$newByteOctal"
  tail -c "+$((address+1))" "$file"
} > patchedFiled
```

If you don't have `head -c`, but the file is very small and does not (!) contain any null byte before the offset, then you can replace `head -c` with

```
printf "%.$((offset1based-1))s" "$(< "$file")"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the system does not have `head` at all, but it does have `printf`. However, the file is about a megabyte so it definitely has null bytes.

Comment: Maybe I forgot to mention - the system has two separate parts, that both have separate filesystems. One of them has all of the commands you would normally need (like `head`, `sed`, etc.). But the one I need is the other one, which does not have any of these commands. That is probably why the second "trimmed" system does not comply with posix standards - to save space.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to do this in `sh` alone. The ways I can think of have to store the null byte inside a variable or argument at some point, which is not possible in `sh`. Maybe someone can think of something viable if you provide a list of programs (`echo`, ...) you actually can use. Can't you access the binaries on the other file system, e.g. by mounting it and then using  `/mnt/otherfs/bin/head -c`?

Comment: Hold on! While making a listing of the system binaries, it turns out that I do have `awk`! Is is possible to use `awk` for this?

Comment: Probably. I tried `LC_ALL=C awk -v RS= -v address=1234 '{printf "%s\567%s", substr($0,0,address-1), substr($0,address+1)}' file > patched` but this sometimes started to deleted `0a` bytes (`\n`) midway for bigger files. Right now I don't have the time to investigate this. But you can edit your question to reflect the current situation and add the awk tag. You might as well add the available awk version (check `awk --version` or `man awk`). Some awk guru will likely find a way.

Comment: Alright, but unfortunately `awk --version` does not return anything and `man` is not installed :/